# c++ function call without struct reference

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ but I have a good programming background and I have been looking for function calls that don't need a reference object to a struct or class. The best referral to what I'm looking for is probably any of unity's classes where for instance Vector2.Distance can be used and it returns another Vector2 but Vector2 is the class!

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct vector {
    float x, y;

    // only recently figured out you could do this
    // instead of vector() {x = 0.0; y = 0.0} etc.
    vector() : x(0.0), y(0.0) {}
    vector(float _x, float _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}

    vector add(vector a, vector b) {
        return vector(this->x + b.x, this->y + b.y);
    }
};

int main() {
    vector a = vector(2, 3);
    vector b = vector(4, 4);

    vector c = vector.add(a, b);

    printf("%f, %f", c.x, c.y);
    return 0;
}

// expected output from this function: 6, 7
```

The code above is an example of what I am wanting, so the reasoning behind what is happening is redundant, I know there is a vector class and I'm sure there is a much simpler way of doing this code in particular but this is the root functionality of what I want.

is this even possible in this language?

```cpp
int main() {
    vector a = vector(2, 3);
    vector b = vector(4, 4);


    this  works: vector c = a.add(a, b);
    this !works: vector c = vector.add(a, b);

    printf("%f, %f", c.x, c.y);
    return 0;
}
```

I am aware that this works but all im trying to do is get rid of needing the A reference in a.add();
I've tried static functions, looking into the std::functional thing, operation overloading but I might have misinterpreted something and came across a solution
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not `a + b` using `operator +`?

Comment: What you’re describing is known as a static function but in C++ you wouldn’t write code like this. You’d either define an *operator* or define the function *outside* the class. Static member functions are very rarely the correct tool in C++ (they’re mostly useful in combination with template metaprogramming, which is a whole different can of worms).

Comment: @tkausl because this example code isnt quite what I want, just the root functionality of what im looking for. the actual code im looking to make is a Color conversion class but my color application has proprietary usage. this is going to convert Colors rgb -> bin and bin -> rgb

Comment: @KonradRudolph hmm, a static function would work in this case if I understand it correctly, my use case doesn't use the this command, but it still doesn't work when I try to call it because you can't call the function through the struct reference

Comment: Or are you looking for `vector add(const vector &b) const { return vector(x + b.x, y + b.y); }`? Call like `a.add(b);`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm the answer below was what I was looking for, but I will keep this in mind; I'm sure I'll need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define *static functions* inside your classes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct vector {
    float x, y;

    // only recently figured out you could do this
    // instead of vector() {x = 0.0; y = 0.0} etc.
    vector() : x(0.0), y(0.0) {}
    vector(float _x, float _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}

    // add "static"
    static vector add(vector a, vector b) {
        return vector(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y); // use correct object
    }
};

int main() {
    vector a = vector(2, 3);
    vector b = vector(4, 4);

    vector c = vector::add(a, b); // use :: instead of .

    printf("%f, %f", c.x, c.y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: … but you probably shouldn’t (in this case).

Comment: @OwenTheProgrammer This is called resolution operator basically we accessed the `add` with in the `struct vector` scope.